# checkpoint SqlContext nullpointerException issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using check pointing in my application, and when my application starts with a failure, I get a `NullPointerException` on `SQLContext`.
I assume the application is not able to recover the `SQLContext` because of serialization/deserialization issues. Is `SQLContext` not serializable?

Here is my code below

```
    //DriverClass
    final JavaSparkContext javaSparkCtx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkCtx);

    JavaStreamingContextFactory javaStreamingContextFactory = new JavaStreamingContextFactory() {
        @Override
        public JavaStreamingContext create() { //only first time executed
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(javaSparkCtx, Durations.minutes(1));
            jssc.checkpoint(CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY);

            HashMap < String, String > kafkaParams = new HashMap < String, String > ();
            kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list",
                            "abc.xyz.localdomain:6667");
            //....
            JavaDStream < String > fullMsg = messages
                                             .map(new MapFunction());

            fullMsg.foreachRDD(new SomeClass(sqlContext));
            return jssc;
        }
    };
}

//Closure Class
public class SomeClass implements Serializable, Function < JavaRDD < String > , Void > {
    SQLContext sqlContext;
    public SomeClass(SQLContext sqlContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.sqlContext = sqlContext;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        this.sqlContext.createDataFrame();**// here is the nullpointerException**
    }
    //.......
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQLContext` is Serializable because Spark SQL needs to use `SQLContext` in the executor side internally. However, you should not serialize it to the Streaming checkpoint. Instead, you should get it from rdd like this `SQLContext sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.context());`

See Streaming docs for more details: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations

Comment: What in case if we are using HiveContext instead of SQLContext?

Comment: If you already created a HiveContext, SQLContext.getOrCreate will just return it.